# How to express "a-part-of" relationship in OWL ontology language?

Tags: owl

How to represent a "part-of" SQL relationship in OWL ontology language?
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE DevelopmentTask (
 DevelopmentTaskID INT,
 SoftwareProjectID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SoftwareProject (SoftwareProjectID),PRIMARY KEY(DevelopmentTaskID, SoftwareProjectID))
```

In the above table the DevelopmentTask table is part of the SoftwareProject. How I can represent this in OWL, may be it can be represented using intersectionOf property in OWL.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can simply introduce an ObjectProperty or a DataTypeProperty depending on what exactly you need to display. For example, I would introduce:

```
hasDevelopmentTask
```

And then add the following restriction:

```
SoftwareProject hasDevelopmentTask some DevelopmentTask
```

The "some" restriction also depends on your relation. If it is 1-n this relation holds, otherwise replace it with "min", "max", "exactly", or "only".

Also, since your example contains IDs, I would add them as instances or individuals of either SoftwareProject or DevelopmentTask. In this case, every instance of SoftwareProject will have "some" DevelopmentTask.

Comment: You forgot the axiom, should be something like `SoftwareProject subClassOf hasDevelopmentTask some DevelopmentTask`

Comment: If I want to write it in XML format, how it will be, below is my try: '<owl:Class rdf:ID="DevelopmentTask"> 
  <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:partOf rdf:resource="#SoftwareProject"/>  
    </owl:Restriction>
  </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
'

Answer (score 3):

As another answer mentioned, you can simply create a property `hasDevelopmentTask`, or something similar.  If you are going to make things a bit more complex in the future (e.g., if a software project has a development task, and a development task a (sub-)development task…) you might want to take a look at the W3C Working Draft, [*Simple part-whole relations in OWL Ontologies*](http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/BestPractices/OEP/SimplePartWhole/).

Comment: If I want to write it in XML format, how it will be, below is my try: '<owl:Class rdf:ID="DevelopmentTask"> 
  <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:partOf rdf:resource="#SoftwareProject"/>  
    </owl:Restriction>
  </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
'

Answer (score 3):

**First, some theory**

OWL doesn't provide built-in primitives for defining `part-whole` relations (as explained in the W3C Working Draft).

However, you can represent `part-of` (and any other non `is-a`) relations using OWL's `objectProperties` and their `restrictions`.

So, in your case you want to define the concept *DevelopmentTask* as *part of* the concept *SoftwareProject*.

In this case, you need to:

1. create an `owl:Class` for each concept (2 classes in this example).
2. create an `owl:ObjectProperty` to represent the relation `partOf` and its restrictions.
3. extend the *part* class to be a `subClassOf` of a restriction over values from the *whole* class on that property.

**Second, the RDF/XML syntax**

So to express that as an OWL ontology in RDF/XML syntax, the final layout would look like this:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="SoftwareProject"/>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="partOf"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="DevelopmentTask">
  <rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="partOf"/>
      <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="SoftwareProject"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
  </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```